# Triple Slash Comments in C?

Tags: c, xml

Does C supports an equivalent of the triple-slash, [XML Documentation Comments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/generate-xml-documentation-comments?view=vs-2019) that Visual Studio uses to provide helpful tooltips for my code in C#, or am U just spoiled by being able to use them in C#?

If it's not supported in C, are there other options?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wfwda74e(v=vs.80).aspx How long did you look?

Comment: Could you clarify what a *triple-slash comment* is? It looks like most people have assumed you meant *double-slash comments*.

Comment: This is not the kind of tag where three slashes means any special.  You are going to have to explain what xml documentation means.  The answer is no btw.

Comment: He means comments that can be parsed by a documentation tool, like Javadoc or Doxygen.

Comment: Spoiled! Certainly spoiled! Some of us still remember times when *double* slash comment was considered a novelty and unnecessary luxury!

Comment: C is even better. It supports *any* number of slashes! (>=2).

Comment: that would be C99 or earlier vendor dialects only

Answer (score 7, accepted):

C does not have any equivalent of XML documentation comments or JavaDoc.

Try [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/).

Comment: Thanks! Finally someone that noticed the XML tag and knew that there was such a thing as a triple slash comment.

Answer (score 7):

In the C language itself, a triple-slash comment is nothing special (they're just double-slash comments that happen to start with a slash).

However, you can use triple-slash comments with [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/).

Comment: c++ triple slash comments also show up in intellisense in visual studio (2012 onwards). [CppTripleSlash](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/22333333-fd6f-4dcb-8223-52701eddd7ad) helps auto-complete the documentation stubs when the triple slash is typed above a function.

Answer (score 2):

Most modern C compilers will understand *double*-slash comments like in C++. They are part of the C99 spec.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably you're talking about creating comment blocks that are formatted for automated extraction.

Doxygen supports [special comment blocks](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html) that start with a double-slash C++ comment delimiter, followed by either another slash, or an exclamation mark.

Answer (score 1):

C supports `/* */` comments.  C99 adds support for `//` comments.  Your IDE or compiler may support more, but that is non-standard.

Comment: It's not up to the IDE, it's up to the compiler. GCC (I tested) ignores everything after `//` , unless you put a `/* comment */` after `//`, at which point some versions will gripe about comments within comments.